# Splitting a result into three columns

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table 'alphabet'. This is just a basic representation/example.

```
id    word
1     a
2     b
3     c
4     d
5     e
6     f
7     g
8     h
9     i
10    j
11    k
12    l
13    m
```

Now assume I am restricted to just a single query (with subqueries) due to a language restriction or otherwise.

I want my 'result' to be as follows:

```
row   col1   col2   col3
1     a      b      c
2     d      e      f  
3     g      h      i
4     j      k      l
5     m
```

Now I've gotten somewhat close to this by emulating a Full Outer Join in MySQL by following the instructions found here: [Full Outer Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql) combined with a sub-query on the same table using something along the lines of:

`SELECT id,word FROM table WHERE MOD(id,3)=1`

This isn't particularly perfect, as it requires me to assume that the ids follow each-other perfectly sequentially, but I haven't been able to think of a better method at the time. Since last I recall, LIMIT and OFFSET do not take sub-queries.

However, following this thought through, results into something along the lines of:

```
row   col1   col2   col3
1     a
2     d
3     g
4     j
5     m
6            b
7            e
8            h
9            k
10                  c
11                  f
12                  i
13                  l
13                  m
```

Is there a way to get my desired format? 
And note that normally, the desired way to do this is indeed to just do three calls with a limit-offset call based on a count(). But /is this possible/ to be done in a single call?

Comment: I cannot think of a situation where this could be useful !!?!?!

Comment: @Strawberry I am working with a niche and limited language. And while I CAN grab a COUNT() ahead of time and feed it as an argument, I am using an equivalent of a function language's MAP() to form answers.
The code in said language gets more messy if I want to feed an argument other than the straight SQL into it.

That aside, you can see it as academic exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doesn't found any use case for this, but it is what you want:

```
SELECT
  FLOOR((id - 1)/3) + 1 id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN MOD(id - 1,3) = 0 THEN word END) col1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN MOD(id - 1,3) = 1 THEN word END) col2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN MOD(id - 1,3) = 2 THEN word END) col3
FROM tbl
GROUP BY FLOOR((id - 1)/3)
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f62cfb/20)**

*Notice, that this will work only in case when you have sequential Id starting from 1.*

Comment: This is the closest answer so far. But as you say, Hamlet, this runs into the problem of sequential IDs.

Comment: @Mercutio This is **exact** answer for question stated in OP. But I predicted the problem and stated it in my answer. As a fast fix you can number the rows in letter order (or any) and use this query.

Comment: Thank you to anonymous down-voters. They always make me smile.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan my fault, please accept my apologies, my intention was to upvote. If you edit the answer I can repair the error.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT FLOOR((col1.id - 1) / 3 + 1) AS id, col1.word AS col1, col2.word AS col2, col3.word AS col3
FROM alphabet col1 
    LEFT JOIN alphabet col2 ON col1.id = col2.id - 1
    LEFT JOIN alphabet col3 ON col2.id = col3.id - 1
WHERE col1.id % 3 = 1;
```

Comment: That results in roughly:
1 a b c
2 d e f
3 g h i
4 j k l
As you can tell, 'm' is missing.

Comment: @Mercutio It works perfectly for me.. did you notice my edits?

Comment: I did not in fact, notice the edits. My apologies. 
This indeed works! The row numbers are not correct in the case of a non-sequential ID, but that is but a minor detail.

Comment: @Mercutio, what about performance? Imagine, you want to break down to 10 - 50 columns.

Comment: @Mercutio don't worry :) but if you finally found the correct solution by yourself you can set your own answer as correct

Comment: @HamletHakobyan you're right this answer is not the optimal one

Comment: @HamletHakobyan (and Javi) 
Could you explain in basic terms, how your two solutions relate to eachother in terms of performance? That is unfortunately an area of Databases I am not too proficient with. I presume that Hamlet's is a more linear search, where-as Javi's spends additional time to do the joins?

Comment: I think in this example performance is not important, but if your alphabet is bigger and you need a higher number of columns, @HamletHakobyan's solution is far better, because no joins are needed.

Comment: I indeed have a far larger database. The example was simply there to get a basic idea across and sift out any unnecessary information. In this case, I'll return to marking Hamlet's answer as the accepted answer. Thank you very much Javi. (Besides, I can't mark mine as accepted for another 2 days, and I feel it'd be bad form not to give Hamlet his due credit).

Comment: @Mercutio that's fine with me :)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
Select t1.id as `row`, t1.word as col1, t2.word as col2, t3.word as col3
From alphabet t1
left join alphabet t2 on t2.id = t1.id + 5
left join alphabet t3 on t3.id = t1.id + 10 
Where t1.id <= 5
```

Comment: While this indeed would solve the problem, it requires me knowing the COUNT() of table ahead of time (thus making it two calls). But I'll play with this for a bit and see if this can go somewhere. And it still runs into the issue I outlined, which is that for anything resembling a decent output, it requires the IDs to be sequential (no gaps/deletions to be present)

Answer (score 0):

Taking Halmet Hakobyan's answer, finishing this off:

```
SELECT
FLOOR((rank - 1)/3) + 1 rank,
  MAX(CASE WHEN MOD(rank - 1,3) = 0 THEN word END) col1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN MOD(rank - 1,3) = 1 THEN word END) col2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN MOD(rank - 1,3) = 2 THEN word END) col3
FROM (SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank, `id`,`word` from tbl) as tbl, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
GROUP BY FLOOR((rank - 1)/3)
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f62cfb/24)**

This will work even if the ids are not in sequence.